# Very basic question about parent() and prev() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, parent

I am handling a hyperlink's click event with a JavaScript function. I want to retrieve data from the hyperlink.

The page looks like this:

```
<div class="div1">
   <div title="Title 1" class="div2">
      <p class="p1"><a class="linkJs">The link in question</a></p>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="div1">
   <div title="Title 2" class="div2">
      <p class="p1"><a class="linkJs">The link in question</a></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript something like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('a.linkJs').click(function(){
      value=$(this).parent().prev().text();
      alert(value);
   });
});
```

What I want to have is the value of the TITLE in the div2. By clicking the first link I get : Title 1.  And by clicking on the 2nd: Title 2.

This must be very very basic but I just can't find my answer anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it with the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
   $('a.linkJs').click(function(){
      value=$(this).closest('div').attr('title');
      alert(value);
   });
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
var value = $(this).closest('div').attr('title');
```

Your problem is that the `<p>` tag is not a sibling to the `<div>` but a child, so you would have to do `parent()` twice - there's no need, though, as the `closest` function is a handy shortcut. Also, the `text()` function returns the pure text contents *inside* the tag, if you want the title attribute of the tag you need to use the `attr` function.

Answer (score 1):

try using the `closest()` method: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

> Get the first ancestor element that
>   matches the selector, beginning at the
>   current element and progressing up
>   through the DOM tree.

```
$(function() {
    $('a.linkJs').click(function(){
        value=$(this).closest(".div2").attr("title");
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = $(this).closest('.div2').attr('title');
```

Instead of using `div`, `.div2` may be a more appropriate selector because there may be other div elements inside `div.div2`.

Answer (score 0):

Not very pretty, but this should work too.

```
$(function() {
    $('a.linkJs').click(function(){
        value=$(this).parents()[1];
        alert($(value).attr('title'));
    });
});
```